# Inserting combination of items in one array list into another array list using angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, arraylist, angular2-forms

I have an arrayList (selectedSources) with items like these:

```
this.selectedSources.push(
  { id: 0, text: "A" },
  { id: 1, text: "B" },
  { id: 2, text: "C" },
  { id: 3, text: "D"}
);
```

The user can select any or all of these items. When the user selects items, I need to move a combination of these items into another array list dynamically.

At the moment I am doing it with `if/else` statements. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

below is my code :

```
  if (
    this.selectedSources.some(x => x.Value === "B") &&
    this.selectedSources.some(x => x.Value === "C")
  ) {
    if (this.formulalist != undefined) {
      //this.formulalist.length = 0;
      this.formulalist = [];
    }
    this.formulalist.push({
      Value: "B - C",
      Name: "B - C",
      IsVisible: true,
      UpdateFlag: "A",
      Market: "",
      FormulaType: "diff",
      FormulaSet1: "1",
      FormulaSet2: "3",
      checked: null
    });
    this.formulalist.push({
      Value: "% B - C",
      Name: "% B - C",
      IsVisible: true,
      UpdateFlag: "A",
      Market: "",
      FormulaType: "percent",
      FormulaSet1: "1",
      FormulaSet2: "3",
      checked: null
    });
   else if (
    this.selectedSources.some(x => x.Value === "B") &&
    this.selectedSources.some(x => x.Value === "D")
  ) {
    if (this.formulalist != undefined) {
      //this.formulalist.length = 0;
      this.formulalist = [];
    }
    this.formulalist.push({
      Value: "B - D",
      Name: "B - D",
      IsVisible: true,
      UpdateFlag: "A",
      Market: "",
      FormulaType: "percent",
      FormulaSet1: "1",
      FormulaSet2: "4",
      checked: null
    });
    this.formulalist.push({
      Value: "% B - D",
      Name: "% B - D",
      IsVisible: true,
      UpdateFlag: "A",
      Market: "",
      FormulaType: "percent",
      FormulaSet1: "1",
      FormulaSet2: "4",
      checked: null
    });
    ............
    ............
```

If the user selects B and C  then I need to push a combination of these items. For example: `(B - C)` and  `% B - C`.

How can we do this dynamically without using hard-coded values,but using the user selection in angular 4

`selectedSources` is having a user selected list.

if the user selects `B,A,C` i need to push these items to another array list 
`A - C, % A - C, A - B, % A - B, B - C, % B - C`

Comment: I am using checkboxes in UI and then add button to push to another array list `user must have to select 2 items from list 1`

Comment: @FerhadOthman sorry Its UI is complicated

Comment: @FerhadOthman i have scenarios like i mentioned in problem

Comment: Please explain what is wrong in my example? and see the update

Comment: @FerhadOthman i am not sure who downvoted you .. thanks for your help i will work on your example ...

Comment: @FerhadOthman i am looking for only combination of items not the individual items could you please modify your code ...

Comment: Do you meen like `['A-B','%A-B'....]`?

Comment: yeah thanks i got it ..

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example here for you I hope it will help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayh1yc

There are 4 checkboxes like in this image 
[image]

and this is the result:[image]